# What is the correct (typical) value for elasticsearch.hosts in kibana.config in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch-opendistro

In the OpenDistro Helm README.md, the [Example Secure Kibana Config With Custom Certs](https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/opendistro-build/blob/main/helm/README.md#example-secure-kibana-config-with-custom-certs) defines:

```
elasticsearch.hosts: https://elasticsearch.example.com:443
```

This would imply a DNS hostname external to the kubernetes cluster. However, the generated name when using the defaults, and not using custom certs, results in:

```
    # If no custom configuration provided, default to internal DNS
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
      value: https://opendistro-es-client-service:9200
```

which comes from kibana-deployment.yaml: `value: https://{{ template "opendistro-es.fullname" . }}-client-service:9200`

Shouldn't a typical Kibana config.yml also use the internal DNS, and therefore still be opendistro-es-client-service:9200, or opendistro-es-client-service.default.svc.cluster.local:9200, assuming for example, default namespace? Why would you *not* use the internal DNS?

UPDATE: There is a similar question with  opendistro_security.nodes_dn for the elasticsearch.config (which is copied to elasticsearch.yml):

```
   # See: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/security/blob/master/securityconfig/elasticsearch.yml.example#L17
opendistro_security.nodes_dn:
  - 'CN=nodes.example.com'
```

It is not spelled out anywhere that I can find, but I am *assuming* this is the CN from Subject of the cert defined by `elasticsearch.ssl.transport.existingCertSecret`.  Again, shouldn't these be, if anything, the internal kubernetes dns names?.

Or does it not matter if `opendistro_security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification` is false"

- The default is `true`
- The value in the default `elasticsearch.yml` (according to the helm README.md) is false.
- The actual example (further down in the README.md), does not set it, so presumably, it is `true`.
- But the actual values.yaml has a commented out value set to `false`. (I presume you are supposed to uncomment that when defining config, which you must do when adding your own certs).

Comment: Giving more visibility to the same question at github page of this helm chart: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/opendistro-build/issues/756

Comment: @DawidKruk Thanks, Yes I should have added that link.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own certificates (best practice is to create separate certificates for node/admin/rest) and inject them into the master pods.
Use those certificate in the kibana.yaml to establish the connection to your ES cluster.

The value for the host is created automatically and is the same as the ES client service object on your cluster. This is how Kibana knows where to connect since the service is routing the requests to your master pods.